# PHP - Load header from another file

Tags: php, html

I've run into problem whereby I'm not able to include a header file into a PHP file

In the code below, I've removed the original content as it's quite big & anyway what the code does is irrelevant to including the header file

**MAIN.PHP**

```
        <?php
 php content
            ?>


            <html>
    <head>  
            </head>
                <body >
                <div>
                   header content
                    </div>

                    <br/>
                    <div>
                </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

I would like to have the following code in the `header.php` file & include it on all pages.

```
            <div>
header content
</div>
```

When I do so with the `main.php` file looking as below, the page draws blank.

```
      <?php
 php content
            ?>


            <html>
    <head>  
            </head>
                <body >
                <div>
                   <? php include('header.php') ?>
                    </div>

                    <br/>
                    <div>
                </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

I've tried debugging this & following a few solutions on stackoverflow, but evidently have failed to achieve what I'm after.

Could I please request a second pair of eyes to help me spot the problem?

Comment: your main.php code does not contain the include line:  <?php include('header.php'); ?> yet your output seems to show <?php include('header.php'); No close tag. Is the header.php file in the same path as the main.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, I don't think you copied the code correctly to here.
As my debugging eyes can see, you got 2 issues:

1. Line 1: `<` is missing at the start. Change it to `<?php`. (Maybe
   copy paste error?)
2. `<?php include('header.php');` is missing closing tag. Change it to:
   `<?php include('header.php'); ?>`

If you get a blank page, you probably have some errors. Try finding the "error.log" file in you working directory or add the following code at the start of the page:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you Gal. Points 1 & 2 in your answer were typos while drafting the question. The debug mechanism helped me trawl through & find the error. It ended up to be that somehow someone has messed up the directory permissions with a sticky bit set & so anything that goes into that directory was messed up. Thank you very much.